# Get specific data from a line of text

Tags: c#, wpf, text, split, trim

I need to extract the following data (in bold) from the text line below and put it into a data grid;

PERS tooldata **t_rrt_ja03579**:=[TRUE,[[**-39.643,-0.001,1025.49**],[**0.382684,-0.000130001,-0.923889,0.000120001**]],[200.9,[-88.1,-12.6,359.7],[1,0,0,0],29.347,50.927,18.261]];

This line is read from a file. I have managed to trim the line so it gets rid of the "PERS tooldata" and whitespaces and it leaves me with the tool name. I have it bound to data in a datagrid elsewhere in the code which is step 1 complete.

My question is how can I extract the values in bold individually and place them in to double data declarations? The first block of values (-39.643,-0.001,1025.49) is a X,Y,Z co-ordinate value and the second (0.382684,-0.000130001,-0.923889,0.000120001) are Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4.

Below is how i done the name

```
    private void AutoFillToolData(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Gives user option to auto populate datagrid
        var AutoFillToolResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to auto populate fields?", "Tool Data", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
        if (AutoFillToolResult == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            // User directs application to the specified file
            System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowser = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (folderBrowser.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Application looks for specific file and removes unwanted data
                string robotBackupPath = folderBrowser.SelectedPath;
                string allDataPath = robotBackupPath + @"\RAPID\TASK1\SYSMOD\ALL_DATA.sys";
                string[] tLines = File.ReadAllLines(allDataPath);
                List<string> toolDataLines = new List<string>();
                foreach (string tLine in tLines)
                {
                    if (tLine.Contains("PERS tooldata") && !tLine.StartsWith("!"))
                    {
                        if (tLine.Contains("tToolChanger")) continue;
                        if (tLine.Contains("tPointer")) continue;
                        if (tLine.Contains("tHome")) continue;
                        toolDataLines.Add(tLine);
                    }
                }

                foreach (string line in toolDataLines)
                {
                    // Gets the name of the tool
                    ToolData toolData = GetToolNameFromLine(line);

                    // Puts the tool name in the DataGrid 
                    TCPData.Add(toolData);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private ToolData GetToolNameFromLine(string line)
    {
        // Removes white space at the beggining of line in txt file
        ToolData tooldata = new ToolData();
        string[] spaceSplit = line.Trim().Split(' ');
        string values = spaceSplit[2];

        // Gets Tool Name
        int colonLocation = values.IndexOf(":");
        tooldata.ToolName = values.Substring(0, colonLocation);
        return tooldata;
    }
```

Comment: Especially for text-filters it isnt bad to provide multiple examples to see static parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the samples you'll have follow the same pattern, extracting those values does not seem difficult:

```
//First we get all the string after the :=
string tooldata = line.Substring(data.IndexOf(":=") + 2) ;

//Split the string by [        
string[] tooldataArray = tooldata.Split(new char[] { '[' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
//the second and the third strings are what we are interested in
string xyzValue  = tooldataArray[1].Replace(']' ,' ');
string Q1234value = tooldataArray[2].Replace(']', ' ');
```

If after this you want to get the individual parameters, just splitting by `,` would do.

**Edit**

This would extract all the values you want to arrays of `double`:

```
string tooldata = data.Substring(data.IndexOf(":=") + 2) ;

string[] tooldataArray = tooldata.Split(new char[] { '[' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
double[] xyzValue  = tooldataArray[1].Replace(']' ,' ')
                    .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(s => double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    .ToArray();
double[] Q1234value = tooldataArray[2].Replace(']', ' ')
                    .Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Select(s => double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    .ToArray();
```